# Plugin com erro Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clone' of undefined

Tags: owl-carousel

Estou usando um plugin chamado Owl Carousel e estou com um problema, se o carrocel tem somente uma imagem me é lançado uma mensagem de erro, que é essa:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clone' of undefined

Li a documentação mas não encontrei a solução, se tenho mais de uma imagem tudo funciona perfeitamente mas uma não.

A mensagem completa do console é essa, estou inserindo como trecho pois a amostra de código está ficando todo desconfigurado.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clone' of undefined
at e.run (owl.carousel.min.js:1)
at Object.e [as run] (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)
at e.update (owl.carousel.min.js:1)
at e.refresh (owl.carousel.min.js:1)
at e.initialize (owl.carousel.min.js:1)
at new e (owl.carousel.min.js:1)
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (owl.carousel.min.js:1)
at Function.each (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)
at m.fn.init.each (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)
at m.fn.init.a.fn.owlCarousel (owl.carousel.min.js:1)
```

O código que mostra as imagens é esse:

```html
<div class="owl-carousel img-carousel">
   <?php foreach($ResImagemGrande as $ResImgGrande) {  
   $ImgProduto = substr($ResImgGrande->Caminho,3);        
 ?>
 <div class="item">
  <a class="btn btn-theme btn-theme-transparent btn-zoom" href="<?php echo $ImgProduto; ?>" data-gal="prettyPhoto"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
  <a href="<?php echo $ImgProduto; ?>" data-gal="prettyPhoto"><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $ImgProduto; ?>" alt=""/></a>
 </div>
 <?php } ?>
</div>


<div class="row product-thumbnails">
<?php 
 $i = -1; 
 foreach($ResImagemPequena as $ResImgPequena) { 
 $i++; 
 $ImgProdutoThumbs = substr($ResImgPequena->CaminhoThumbs,3); 
?>

 <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-3">
 <a href="#" onclick="jQuery('.img-carousel').trigger('to.owl.carousel', [<?php echo $i ?>,300]);"><img src="<?php echo $ImgProdutoThumbs; ?>" alt=""/></a>                            
 </div>
<?php } ?>  
</div>
```

A página em desenvolvimento pode ser vista aqui:
[Desenvolvimento](https://rendamaislingerie.com.br/detalhes.php?Id=15)

Comment: Consegue adicionar o código que você está utilizando para adicionar o carousel às imagens na pergunta?

Comment: Foi adicionado o código solicitado @edsonalves.

Comment: Opa, mas você não tem um trecho do JS que usa pra adicionar o plugin no DOM? Deve se parecer com  `$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel(...);`

Comment: Olá @edsonalves, na página eu tenho essa chamada aqui:
<script src="https://rendamaislingerie.com.br/assets/plugins/owl-carousel2/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver o meu problema com uma verificação da quantidade de registros retornados da pesquisa, meio `tabajara` mas deu certo, fiz um `IF` para mostrar a classe quando existir mais de um `Thumb` gerado, senão, mostra normalmente uma imagem grande, existindo mais de um `Thumb`, mostra a imagem grande e o `carrocel`, fiz assim:

```html
<!-- MOSTRAR OU NÃO CARROCEL -->                   
<div <?php if ($ContRegImgPequena > 1) { ?> class="owl-carousel img-carousel" <?php } ?> >
<?php foreach($ResImagemGrande as $ResImgGrande) {  
  $ImgProduto = substr($ResImgGrande->Caminho,3);        
 ?>
 <div class="item">
  <a class="btn btn-theme btn-theme-transparent btn-zoom" href="<?php echo $ImgProduto; ?>" data-gal="prettyPhoto"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
  <a href="<?php echo $ImgProduto; ?>" data-gal="prettyPhoto"><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $ImgProduto; ?>" alt=""/></a>
 </div>
 <?php } ?>
</div>
<!-- MOSTRAR OU NÃO CARROCEL -->          
<?php if ($ContRegImgPequena > 1) { ?>        
<div class="row product-thumbnails">
<?php 
 $i = -1; 
 foreach($ResImagemPequena as $ResImgPequena) { 
 $i++; 
 $ImgProdutoThumbs = substr($ResImgPequena->CaminhoThumbs,3); 
?>

 <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-3">
 <a href="#" onclick="jQuery('.img-carousel').trigger('to.owl.carousel', [<?php echo $i ?>,300]);"><img src="<?php echo $ImgProdutoThumbs; ?>" alt=""/></a>                            
 </div>
 <?php } ?>  
</div>
<?php  } ?>
```